# Database driver Cake\Database\Driver\Sqlserver cannot be used due to a missing PHP extension or unmet dependency

Tags: database-connection, cakephp-3.0

I have installed cakephp 3.0.10 having mssql database now i have configured my wamp (php 5.5.12) with

```
extension=php_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_55_ts.dll
```

& php info showing that sqlsrv is configured.
I have configured App.php with following code

```
'default' => [
            'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
            'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Sqlserver',
            'persistent' => true,
            'host' => 'mypc\SQLEXPRESS',
            'username' => '',
            'password' => '',
            'database' => 'testdbname',
            'encoding' => 65001,//PDO::SQLSRV_ENCODING_UTF8,
            'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
    'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
```

To check whether connection is working or not i created a index.php file and fetched data from a test db created in sql magt. 2012 Now problem is cake php is not getting connected with database and it is showing following error

Database driver Cake\Database\Driver\Sqlserver cannot be used due to a      missing PHP extension or unmet dependency

```
Exception Attributes: array (
    'driver' => 'Cake\\Database\\Driver\\Sqlserver', 
)
```

crud operation  are going well in index.php ( test file ) but cakephp flashing error 
Please help me to sort this out.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I have my doubts that this happens while `phpinfo()` shows that the drivers are available. Please add a screenshot of the relevant `phpinfo()` sections.

Comment: yes phpinfo showing all the drivers but problem is with cakephp3.x its Sqlserver class not supporting the mssql i guess. If i were on cakephp 2.0 it would have worked definitely cuz i am currently working on cakephp 2.0 so the problem is with cakephp 3.0 sqlserver class file

Comment: This is how CakePHP tests for the driver being available/useable: **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.0.11/src/Database/Driver/Sqlserver.php#L93** And it's true for me as soon as I enable the `pdo_sqlsrv` extension (if it returns `false`, the connection will throw the exception that you're seeing). So again, please add a screenshot of the relevant `phpinfo()` output. And while you're already at it, you could have a look at `PDO::getAvailableDrivers()` too. Also, when receiving errors, please always attach the related stacktrace!